# How can i write condition in jqgrid colmodel

Tags: php, jqgrid

Can u help me. I have the following colmodel:

```html
colNames: ["Name","Value", "upper limit", "lower limit", "stock"],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Num', index:'num', align:"center", sortable:false,width: 40, resizable:false },
                { name: 'Value', index:'Value', align:"center", width: 70,
                    cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                        // {
                        //     if (rawObject[1] >= 300 || rawObject[1] <= 50) {
                        //         var colorText = 'style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 24px;+colorText"';
                        //     } else {
                        //         var colorText = 'style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 24px;color:red"';
                        //     };  return(colorText);}},
                        console.log (rawObject[1])
                    }},

                {name:'upper', index:'upper', align:"center", width: 25, resizable:false,editable:true,
                    cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject){return 'style="font-size: 15px;"';}},
                {name:'lower', index:'lower', align:"center", width: 25, resizable:false, editable:true,
                    cellattr: function(rowId, val, rawObject){return 'style="font-size: 15px;"';}},
                { name: 'stock', index:'stock', align:"center", sortable:false,width: 40, resizable:false }
                ],
```

Below is what I get from get-data.php.

```
$array = array(
array("1","$f1rst", "300","50"),//: Закладочный ствол
array("2","$second","350","60"),//: Клетьевой ствол
array("3","$three","120","20"),//: Портал
array("4","$four","200","20"),//: Скиповой ствол
array("5","$five","200","0"));//: ЦВС


//var_dump($array);
if (empty($array)) {
    echo '["Нет данных"]';
}
else {echo json_encode($array);}
```

[index.php example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fku5I.jpg)

I need to compare values. For example: there is the first value in the first cell equal to 60. If 'value'> = 300 or 'value' <= 50, then paint the cell red.
Next, the second cell. If value> = 350 or value <= 60. And so with all five meanings.

upd.
In my example, the code doesn't work. It does a conditional check on the entire column. And I need for each cell

upd2.
see how it works
[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: I am using version jqGrid  4.6.0

Comment: This version is too old and maybe contain a bug regarding the code similar to you.

Comment: I installed version 5.5.4. The whole point of my problem is not that the code is not working. And the fact is that I cannot refer to the desired cell. The code selects the entire column, butI want to refer to the desired row and the desired column.

Comment: Not sure wht you do, but here [example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/jess/) which do the same think as you. Maybe you have additinally in your code **rowattr** event, which maybe overwrite your **cellattr**. That is the reason to ask the entire jqGrid code and not the part, since other part can overwrite your code.

Comment: glad to hear that you have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony Tomov gave the correct answer. Thank you very much, everything worked out and everything works

Below is a link to an example

[example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/jess/)

```
 {label: 'Название', name: 'Num', index: 'num', align: "center", sortable: false, width: 40, resizable: false},
        {
          label: 'Значение', name: 'Value', index: 'Value', align: "center", width: 70,
          cellattr: function (rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
            if (rdata["Num"] === '1' && (rdata['Value'] >= 300 || rdata['Value'] <= 50)) {
              return ' class="class1" ';
            } else if (rdata["Num"] === '2' && (rdata['Value'] >= 350 || rdata['Value'] <= 60)) {
              return ' class="class1" ';
            } else if (rdata["Num"] === '3' && (rdata['Value'] >= 120 || rdata['Value'] <= 20)) {
              return ' class="class1" ';
            } else if (rdata["Num"] === '4' && (rdata['Value'] >= 200 || rdata['Value'] <= 20 || isNaN(rdata['Value']))) {
              return ' class="class1" ';
            } else if (rdata["Num"] === '5' && (rdata['Value'] >= 200 || rdata['Value'] <= 0)) {
              return ' class="class1" ';
            }
          }
        },
```